# Die Bedeutung von "Schwarz vor Augen werden"

Tags: meaning

From [Spiegel Online](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/tv/tagesschau-in-der-schweiz-sprecherin-krank-sendung-abgebrochen-a-1014935.html):

> Die Hauptausgabe der Schweizer "Tagesschau" hat am Sonntagabend ein abruptes Ende gefunden. Während einer Live-Schalte nach Griechenland wurde der Sprecherin Cornelia Boesch plötzlich **schwarz vor Augen,** wie der Sender SRF via Twitter mitteilte.

Was bedeutet **Schwarz vor Augen werden**?  Die Internetswörterbücher haben mir kein Ergebnis gegeben.

Comment: If you quote a paragraph from a newspaper, it would be cool if you could indicate that as a quote. I did it for this one.

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Auge

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The English equivalent is *to black out* or *everything went black*.

Example:

> English: I blacked out.
>   German: Mir wurde schwarz vor Augen.

Answer (score 4):

Der Ausdruck „jemandem wird schwarz vor Augen“ ist eine feste Wendung und bedeutet „jemand wird ohnmächtig“ (englisch: *to black out; to pass out; to faint*).

Im Duden – *Redewendungen* findet man den folgenden Eintrag:

> **jemandem wird [es] schwarz vor [den] Augen:** *jemand wird ohnmächtig:*
>   Die Luft war so stickig im Zimmer, dass ihr beinahe schwarz vor Augen geworden wäre.
>   Der Arzt stochert in der Wunde herum, dass mir schwarz vor den Augen wird.